# Where to store user type

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend and not sure on how to go about this problem:

After a user logs in and gets authenticated, I make a query and retrieve the user's roles. From what I understood, a Zend_Registry variable is only global if it is set inside the bootstrap. Is it possible to create a global variable inside the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Zend_Registry` is a container, and you can put stuff into it whenever you want. But obviously you have to put data into it before being able to pull from it (in a request life-cycle that is).

Though if you're using `Zend_Auth` and it's Database adapter (`Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable`), you can simply put user row in session.